# Can anybody help me with my hangman game?

Tags: php, html, arrays

i am doing a hangman game and i would like to save the letter that was introduced and the secret word in a cookie, but i have an error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\clase\EJERCICIOS\ahorcado\ahorcado.php on 
>   line 46
>   _get letra introducida no existe , valor de la variable Array ["txtLetra"]
>   Notice: Undefined index: c_palabra_base in C:\xampp\htdocs\clase\EJERCICIOS\ahorcado\ahorcado.php 
>   on line 53
>   _cookie c_palabra_base no existe , valor de la variable

Here is my code:

```
<pre>
    <?php
echo <<< HTML

<HTML>
<TITLE> ...::AHORCADO::...</TITLE>
    Bienvenido, por favor para empezar introduce una letra
<BODY>

    Introduce una letra <input type="text" name="txtLetra"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="btnOk"><br>


</BODY>     
</HTML>


HTML;

$palabras = array (
        "pueblerino",
        "paleto",
        "campo",
        "vacas",
        "ganadero" 
);
$contarArray = count ( $palabras );
$random = rand ( 0, $contarArray - 1 );
$cad = $palabras [$random];

echo "$cad";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen ( $cad ); $i ++) {
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"letra\" size = 5 readonly></td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "<table>";

if (isset ( $_GET ["txtLetra"] )) {
    print_r (" letra introducida(txtLetra) " . $_GET ["txtLetra"] . "<br>");

    $letraIntroducida = $_GET ["txtLetra"];
    //estoy imprimiento array?????
    setcookie ( "c_letra_introducida", $letraIntroducida );
} else
    print_r( "_get letra introducida no existe , valor de la variable " . "$_GET [\"txtLetra\"]");
if (isset ( $_COOKIE ["c_letra_introducida"] )) {
    echo "letra introducida (cookie) " . $_COOKIE ["c_letra_introducida"] - "<br>";
    setcookie ( "c_palabra_base", $cad );
    echo "c_palabra_base" . $_COOKIE ["c_palabra_base"] . "</br>";
} else
    echo "_cookie c_palabra_base no existe , valor de la variable " . $_COOKIE ["c_palabra_base"];

?>

<code>
```

Comment: The notice you are seeing is because you are using print_r to print a string.
Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that it would be easier for users to help you.

Comment: @iLot `print_r` is perfectly capable of printing a string.

Comment: Question titles are supposed to be technicaly *summaries* of the actual topic, not about help pleading. It also would be suitable to translate text, comments and variables into English.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: Please correct the question's title to more specific one, read documentation of right question formating.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax issue is not the `setcookie` call but:

```
  "$_GET [\"txtLetra\"]"
```

That's not an array access, but would try to interpolate the `$_GET` array in a string, and append a literal `["txtWhatever"]` afterwards.

Either use PHP3 simple string interpolation syntax, or curly brackets around, or don't put it in [double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) to begin with.